# Find derivative using definition, but stuck in finding limit

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

Given $f(x)=x^2-\dfrac{1}{x}+1$. Find $f'(x)$ using definition of derivative.

I try as follows
:

\begin{align}
f'(x) &= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{(x+h)^2-\dfrac{1}{x+h}+1-\left(x^2-\dfrac{1}{x}+1\right)}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{x^2+2hx+h^2-\dfrac{1}{x+h}+1-x^2+\dfrac{1}{x}-1}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \dfrac{2hx+h^2-\dfrac{1}{x+h}+\dfrac{1}{x}}{h}\\
&= \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left( 2x+h -\dfrac{1}{h(x+h)}+\dfrac{1}{hx}\right)
\end{align}

Now, I can't find the limit because there are terms $-\dfrac{1}{h(x+h)}$ and $\dfrac{1}{hx}$. As $h\to 0$, the value is $\infty$. Anyone can explain how to solve the limit above to find derivative of $f(x)$?

Comment: $\dfrac1{x+h}-\dfrac1x=-\dfrac h{x(x+h)}$

Comment: Combine the two fractions into a single fraction.

Comment: Yes, after I combine two fractions into a single fraction, I can get the result of limit. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left( 2x+h -\dfrac{1}{h(x+h)}+\dfrac{1}{hx}\right)$$
Separating the limit:
$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left( 2x+h\right)-  \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{h(x+h)}-\dfrac{1}{hx}\right)$$
$$2x- \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(\dfrac{x}{hx(x+h)}-\dfrac{x+h}{hx(x+h)}\right)$$
$$2x+ \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(\dfrac{h}{hx(x+h)}\right)$$
$$2x+ \lim\limits_{h\to 0} \left(\dfrac{1}{x(x+h)}\right)$$
$$\color{green}{2x+ \dfrac{1}{x^2}}$$